# Symfony redirects to login after successful login...sometimes

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, authentication, fosuserbundle

I've been having an issue with Symfony 3.3.9. Sometimes, not always, when a user logs in with the correct username and password, it redirects to the main page like it should, but then back to the login page.

I know the user is logged in because I can grab the user's information with twig from the login page.

It is really strange, because this doesn't happen all the time. It seems random and difficult to reproduce.

I've been looking into this issue for days and can't figure out why this is happening. Looking for some suggestions.

Thanks.

## Edit-1 added code

## Edit-2

*When I get redirected to the login, I've tried typing the main page url to manually go there. This doesn't work, even though I am logged in. If I wait a minute or so however, this does work.*

---

I'm using the FOS user bundle

here's my config.yml

```
# fos bundle  
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Acme\Entity\User
```

here's my security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_EMPLOYEE:    [ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_MANAGER:     [ROLE_EMPLOYEE]
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_MANAGER]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: after_login
                # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
                # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            switch_user:  true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } 
        
        - { path: ^/administration/roe, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/administration/generateaccessemployees, role: ROLE_ADMIN } 
        - { path: ^/administration/location, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/administration/payroll/closepp, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/administration/t4, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/administration/eft, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/administration/stubmessage, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/administration/payroll_reminder, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/administration, role: ROLE_MANAGER }  
        - { path: ^/admin/exit_impersonation, role: ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
```

In my login_content.html.twig, I'm able to see:

```
{{ app.user.username }}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely would need to see some code, more specifically to help get to the root of the problem whatever function is run on login.

**EDIT:**
In the security.yml you can specify a login_path, in example:

```
my_firewall:
    pattern: ^/(secured_area)/
    provider: my_provider
    anonymous: ~
    form_login:
        login_path:  my_login_path
        default_target_path: /dashboard
```

And in the routing.yml you can map the route as:

```
my_login_path:

pattern:   /my/relative/url/for/login
defaults:  { _controller: MySecurityBundle:Security:login }
```

then you can use an a normal route, in you specific case:

```
return $this->forward($this->generateUrl('my_login_path'));
```

The only reason I suggest this is because default routing after login is causing issues for you.

Comment: Should I not use the FOSUserBundle then? Also, do you have any ideas why this only happens sometimes?

Comment: @HamsterFilter I'm actually unable to reproduce the issue you are having so I would not really be able to shed any light on to why it's happening.

Comment: Something else which is weird is that after it redirects me to the login, if I type in the main page url it will redirect me back to the login. After a minute or so though, this is not the case. I can type the url in and it will work.